# How to get the vertices of a three.js model on a specific height?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a three.js model of an object. Now I'm interested in the contours on different heights(corner points as well as some points on curves to determine curvature). At the moment we convert our model to an object in a CSG Library(csg.js), intersect it with a small flat box(because just a plane is not possible somehow) on that specific height and then create an image and use OpenCV findContours() to get back the points we're interested in.

This process gets somewhat slow the bigger the models get and the more slices I have, so I wondered whether you guys know of a better way to tackle that problem. Maybe I just oversaw something in the documentation that would help me, but so far I couldn't find anything that looked like it would help me.

The contours might be convex and concave depending on the object, so the solution needs to be generic on that part.

I'd really appreciate any input or pointer to something that might help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shaderMaterial. In the uniforms, set

```
myUniforms = {
    uClipPlane:   { type: "v4", value: new THREE.Vector4( 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -300.0) }, 
    clipOffset:  { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
}
```

The clipPlane defines a plane where you will be clipping the object. The clipOffset defines the tolerance on the clipping process.

In the vertex shader, set

```
vec4 pos4 = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); 
vClip = dot ( uClipPlane, pos4);
```

And in the fragment shader, set

```
if (vClip < 0 || vClip > clipOffset ) discard;
```

The reason you need a clipOffset is the same that you need a box in your process, the points  in your shape will never be in an exact plane, but at some small distance of the plane.

Comment: Would this only give me the points that are defined in the model on that height or also for example the point on a vertical edge that goes through the plane?

And the points would be unordered, right? So there would be no easy way to detect which order of points would create the contour of the figure on the specific height?

Comment: That will give you exactly the same that you currently have, but faster. (Or at least I think so). It will give you the points that are in your rendered model, coming from the vertices, the edges and the faces. And no, you don't get vertex information.

Comment: That's unfortunate as I at least need the contour information additionally to the points. And creating that without any vertex information is impossible I guess because it's ambiguous. If I didn't need that information your answer would be awesome. Sorry for not properly specifying the need for the contour information rather than only  points in the question.